# Woocommerce - Precio oferta con rango de días no funciona

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Me ha pasado en 3 Woocommerce distintos, que tenía precios programados en Oferta para esta semana y me encuentro con el problema de que se activa, pero en el precio de oferta me aparece el precio regular.
Se arregla si edito producto por producto y le quito, por ejemplo, la fecha de inicio y guardo.
El problema es que tengo demasiados productos y no encuentro la solución. Adjunto pantallazos para una mejor explicación.

Edición de producto inicial:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado de producto en el mismo Panel y en la parte pública:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dato comentar que no tengo plugins de caché (en la que tenía lo he desactivado) y tampoco tengo un tema hijo que pueda sobreescribir la función del precio. También tengo el Woocommerce actualizado.

Gracias,

Comment: Que hora, fecha y zona horaria tiene configurado el servidor ?

Comment: Hola Cesar. Fecha local de Madrid tanto en el servidor como en el Wordpress. Lo he revisado pensando que el problema era de eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalmente es un bug del Woocommerce, precisamente del WP CRON.
En la fecha de inicio he puesto el día de hoy, 25/11/2019, pero gracias al plugin "WP CONTROL" he podido ver que el hook "woocommerce_scheduled_sales" (quien se encarga de actualizar el precio de oferta), tenía marcado pasar el 25/11/2019 a las 23h para mi sorpresa.

Con este mismo plugin, he podido realizar una ejecución del hook "woocommerce_scheduled_sales" y ya se ve todo correctamente.

Dejo el link de donde encontré ayuda: https://linksoftwarellc.com/blog/woocommerce-scheduled-sales/